# openid along with oauth?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, openid, oauth, oauth-provider

In my application, users sign in/sign out via openid ( same as stackoverflow ).

I would like to open up my application a bit via oauth to third party applications.

How do I create my app  which is openid-consumer to make it oauth-provider?

Is there some standard library etc out there? I am basically working in app engine and python.

edit :

Maybe I did not clearly state my problem. I am using OpenID for authentication. So I do not have user passwords, just their unique federated Identity. My application needs to use third party application. I.e. kind of application that runs inside orkut and facebook. (Do you think opensocial is a a viable option instead of OAuth??)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OAuth python libraries are listed on this page:
http://oauth.net/code/

Comment: is there any particular library that can work as "OAuth Provider" in python that works in app engine. thanks for the link.

Comment: I haven't used any of these libraries, so can't vouch for them.  That being said, one of the python libraries on that page is listed as an OAuth Provider for Django, and Django runs on App Engine.  Also, the first library in the list includes this example code:
http://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2/tree/master/example/  (I haven't looked closely, so I'm not sure if server.py is supposed to be an OAuth provider or just some web server classes for an OAuth consumer.)

Answer (score 2):

OAth and OpenID are had [native support](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes) by app engine sinve 1.3.4. So you can implement transparent and solid authorization/authentication mechanism.

Comment: Although it's worth noting that the OAuth API only works for users who are logged in through Google accounts, not through other OpenID providers (http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/oauth/overview.html#OAuth_and_App_Engine).